# How to get Counter to print frequency of unique words from each line of the input text file to the corresponding line on the output text file?

Tags: python, counter, python-3.4, frequency, word-frequency

I have a homework question. I am supposed to write a function called "WordsByLine", which is supposed to count the frequency of unique words per line in the file and print the frequency of unique words to the corresponding line in an output file. My professor told us what the output is supposed to look like. For example, if the input text file says:

`one fish two fish
red fish blue fish`

(one fish two fish is the first line. red fish blue fish is the second line.)

The output has to look like this:

`two:1 one:1 fish:2
red:1 blue:1 fish:2`

The first line in the output is the frequency of unique words for the first line and then same for the second line.

Here is my code:

```
def wordsByLine(inFile, outFile):
    from collections import Counter
    outFile = open(outFile, 'w')
    with open(inFile, 'r') as f:
        freqs = Counter(f.readline().split())
    outFile.write(str(freqs))
    outFile.close()
print(wordsByLine('input.txt','output.txt'))
```

But here is my output in the text file. It only prints out the first line.:

`Counter({'two':1, 'one':1, 'fish':2})`

How do I get the Counter to skip a line and print the frequency of unique words for the next line (from the next line in the input file)?

Comment: Don't import inside a function. That is almost never a good idea.

Comment: Two notes: 1) your assignment was to write a function that counts the words *per line*: your function should just work on one line, and print out the frequency. 2) you are not currently looping through all the lines of the file, but you just read one line.

Comment: Every time you `open(outFile, 'w')` it creates a new file. You want `open(outFile, 'wa')` to append to any existing file. Would be better to just open the file once and write each successive output line to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, you only ever read a single line with `f.readline`. Also, you likely want to format your text instead of printing out the string representation of a `Counter` object:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> def words_by_line(infile, outfile):
...     with open(infile) as f1, open(outfile, 'w') as f2: 
...         for line in f1:
...             counts = Counter(line.split())
...             string_gen = ("{}:{}".format(k,v) for k,v in counts.items())
...             f2.write(" ".join(string_gen) + "\n")
... 
>>> words_by_line('input.txt','output.txt')
```

Result:

```
(trusty)juan@localhost:~$ cat output.txt 
fish:2 two:1 one:1
fish:2 red:1 blue:1
(trusty)juan@localhost:~$
```

Comment: Thank you so much this was the correct answer and by the way, the (trusty)juan@localhost:~$ cat output.txt did not come out. Same with (trusty)juan@localhost:~$. Good thing those two junky didn't come out. But I am fine now!